# wordpress php - add html to dashboard menu

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress theme and within the theme is a dashboard theme. I want to add a logo and some text above the first menu item in the wordpress admin dashboard menu. Without editing any core wordpress files I figured the best way to do this is to insert it using jquery.

Here is my current code - the php adds the jquery code to the head of the admin area:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'dashboard_menu_logo');

function dashboard_menu_logo() {
  echo '<script type="javascript/text">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#adminmenu").html("<div class="hello">Hello</div>");
    });

</script>';
}
```

I think the issue is that the page is loading this script after it has populated everything (but I might be wrong) - either way it's not doing anything. Can anyone help with a solution to add html to the admin menu

Comment: has jquery been loaded before the point where this code snippet gets inserted? if it gets loaded later, you'll be just getting "undefined function" or whatever.

Comment: Take a look at this:https://wordpress.org/plugins/sweet-custom-dashboard/  If it doesn't do the trick just Google wordpress plugin modify dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use admin_menu action. Title area supported html tags.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'createMenu');
function createMenu() {
    add_menu_page('Page Title', '<strong style="color:lightcoral">YOUR HTML CODE</strong>', 'administrator', 'click-action', 'your_new_menu', 'your-favicon-path', 61);
}
```